# Converting long data to wide format (and repeating row values into a single cell)

Tags: data-transfer, transform

I need a simple solution(s) for transforming long data, including repeating rows for subjects, to wide format (repeating row values are put into a single cell).

[image]

**What may be the simplest option for doing this?** Pivot tables?